# Setting attribute values using PyQGIS in an edit session

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

My PyQGIS script works fine if I am not in an edit session, but 99% of the time I will be, so I need it to work whilst in editing mode.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("test")[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)

value='222'
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        feature['flag1'] = value
        layer.updateFeature(feature)

msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setText("All done.")
msg.show()
```

So basically, it just updates the 'flag1' field with the assigned value for those features that have already been selected from the 'test' layer. How do I make this work inside an edit session? Currently I receive this error:

> File
> "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py",
> line 38, in **enter**
> assert self.layer.startEditing() AssertionError

Comment: I get: TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object does not support indexing. As I said, the script works, but I need it to work within an edit session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start a new edit session if the layer is already in one.

You need to test if your layer is in an edit session and if it's the case, don't open a new one. [QgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.isEditable) has a method `isEditable()` wich returns a boolean, `true` if the layer is in an edit session. You can use it to test your layer and know what to do.

This code should work :

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("test")[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)

value='222'

if layer.isEditable() :
    for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        feature['flag1'] = value
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
else :
    with edit(layer):
        for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
            feature['flag1'] = value
            layer.updateFeature(feature)

msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setText("All done.")
msg.show()
```

Comment: additionally, I had a 'check if writable, make readonly' check in my code, whilst using the 'with edit()'. For some reason this really upset the with edit() command, when I removed the check if editable/makereadonly, the code worked. Not sure why though unfortunately, but worth mentioning.