# AssertionError when applying expression to field value with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, editing, features, length, assertionerror

I am trying create new columns in an attribute table and fill them with values with expressions using Python Console in QGIS.

I successfully create the new columns but when I try to fill them, I get an assertion error. Here is an example for one column :

```py
layer=QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\ANI\Documents\SIG\fossés\pythontest\mergedlinef1.shp")
features=layer.getFeatures()

layer_provider=layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("long",QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields()

layer.startEditing()
exp_long = QgsExpression("$length")
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.SetFeature(f)
        f['long'] = exp_long.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

And the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py", line 38, in __enter__
    assert self.layer.startEditing()
AssertionError
```

Line 23 refers to the line `with edit(layer):`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`AssertionError`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-assertion-error/) appeared because of the `with edit(layer):` which was used just after the layer was already brought to the edit mode with `layer.startEditing()`, so there is no need to double edit it.

A solution is to erase the first statement `layer.startEditing()`. Another workaround was shown in this thread [Setting attribute values using PyQGIS in an edit session](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380828/99589).

```py
layer=QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\ANI\Documents\SIG\fossés\pythontest\mergedlinef1.shp")
features=layer.getFeatures()

layer_provider=layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("long",QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields()

exp_long = QgsExpression("$length")
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['long'] = exp_long.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Ongoing another error `AttributeError: 'QgsExpressionContext' object has no attribute 'SetFeature'` will appear because of the `SetFeature(f)` method which should be [`setFeature(f)`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Expression/QgsExpressionContext.html#qgis.core.QgsExpressionContext.setFeature).

To simplify your code, you can write it as this

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\ANI\Documents\SIG\fossés\pythontest\mergedlinef1.shp")
fields = layer.fields()
fields_names = layer.fields().names()

new_field = "long"

if new_field not in fields_names:
    layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
    layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField(new_field, QVariant.Double)])
    layer.updateFields()

layer.startEditing()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    feature[new_field] = feature.geometry().length()
    layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.commitChanges()
```

However, **note the differences between `$length` and `length($geometry)`:**

From the [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry-functions):

[`$length`](https://docs.qgis.orglatest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#length):

> Returns the length of a linestring. If you need the length of a border
> of a polygon, use `$perimeter` instead. The length calculated by this
> function respects both the current project’s ellipsoid setting and
> distance unit settings. For example, if an ellipsoid has been set for
> the project then the calculated length will be ellipsoidal, and if no
> ellipsoid is set then the calculated length will be planimetric.

[`length($geometry)`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id29):

> Returns the number of characters in a string or the length of a
> geometry linestring.

---

**References:**

- [Calculating line lengths using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168871/calculating-line-lengths-using-pyqgis)
- [Calculating length of line shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379515/calculating-length-of-line-shapefile-using-pyqgis)
- [How to handle AssertionError in Python and find out which line or statement it occurred on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587223/how-to-handle-assertionerror-in-python-and-find-out-which-line-or-statement-it-o)
- [PyQGIS 101: Using expressions to compute new field values](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/)
- [Tutorials Point | Assertions in Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assertions_in_python.htm)

Comment: Thank you, problem solved!